# Power operator inconsistency

Tags: excel, matlab, math, operators, wolfram-mathematica

I hope this won't end as philosophical question, but which of theese is the right result of `(2^5^2)`

Excel:

[image]

Matlab:

[image]

Wolfram|Alpha: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2%5E5%5E2

33554432

I know I can add braces to get desired behavior, but I want to know why those Math softwares are implementing it differently?

Comment: There's no clear standard on whether `^` should be left or right associative. Most of the time, `x ** y ** z` => `(x ** y) ** z` but you (obviously) can't rely on that behavior. Really `x ** y ** z` is just an ambiguous expression, and shouldn't be used.

Comment: To add to the comment of @CollinD: even if you *know* the order of evaluation of these expressions in a given language, you should not (ab)use it, since it's 1. prone to errors, 2. horribly confusing to anyone else looking at your code.

Comment: Without getting too into the math - I'd go with Wolfram Alpha's answer.  Of course, the context of this number (and where the 2, 5, and 2 came from) would guide to the correct answer.  But, without more info, the math would be `2^(5^2)`.  Doing `(2^5)^2` would be incorrect, since you want 2 raised to the fifth, which itself is raised to the second.  What are these numbers to represent? Where's your formula coming from?

Comment: Formula is example made up to test the inconsistency of handling the power operator. I was wondering if the results those first class math softwares are giving are actually mathematically incorrect, or just result of uncertainty how to parse given expression & simply performing same precedence as with `*,/,+,-` operators. Is this the reason why most modern programing languages do not implement power operator at all?

Comment: I'd argue there is no "mathematical correctness" because neither "**" or "^" operators are used in mathematical notation.  The mathematical superscript convention makes it obvious that the order is top-right to bottom-left, but that becomes a language choice when translating to an operator notation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In MATLAB operators of equal precedence are always evaluated [left to right](http://au.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/operator-precedence.html?refresh=true) which explain the result you are seeing. The same is true with [Excel](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Calculation-operators-and-precedence-48be406d-4975-4d31-b2b8-7af9e0e2878a). 
In essence they are assuming that operations are always left associative. Wolfram alpha, as well as [Mathematica](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/OperatorInputForms.html) define exp. as right associative which afaik is more 'correct' mathematically. In doubt use parenthesis.